# BarcodeDetector DOMException: Barcode detection service unavailable (in Chrome)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, qr-code

We are currently trying to use the native [BarcodeDetector](https://wicg.github.io/shape-detection-api/#barcode-detection-api) in the latest Chrome (59). It is available under the enabled flag `chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features`.

You can have look at another example [here](https://paul.kinlan.me/barcode-detection/).

We are checking for the native BarcodeDetector like this:

```
typeof window.BarcodeDetector === 'function'
```

But even when we fall into this branch and we finally manage to pour some image data into the detector we only get an exception:

> DOMException: Barcode detection service unavailable.

I've googled that, but was not very successful. The most promising hint is [this one](https://github.com/scheib/chromium/blob/master/third_party/WebKit/Source/modules/shapedetection/BarcodeDetector.cpp#L34), but it seems to be an odd Webkit fork.

What we are doing is the following (pseudocode!):

```
window.createImageBitmap(canvasContext.canvas) // from canvasEl.getContext('2d')
  .then(function(data)
  {
    window.BarcodeDetector.detect(data);
  });
  // go on: catch the exception
```

Has anybody ever heard of this and can share some experiences with the `BarcodeDetector`?

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same error using the desktop version of Chrome. I guess at the moment it is only implemented in the mobile version.

Here is an example that worked for me (Android 5.0.2, Chrome 59 with chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features enabled): https://jsfiddle.net/daniilkovalev/341u3qxz/

```
navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then((devices) => {
  let id = devices.filter((device) => device.kind === "videoinput").slice(-1).pop().deviceId;
  let constrains = {video: {optional: [{sourceId: id }]}};

  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constrains).then((stream) => {
    let capturer = new ImageCapture(stream.getVideoTracks()[0]);
    step(capturer);
  });
});

function step(capturer) {
    capturer.grabFrame().then((bitmap) => {
      let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
      let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      ctx.drawImage(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.width, bitmap.height, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      var barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector();
      barcodeDetector.detect(bitmap)
        .then(barcodes => {
          document.getElementById("barcodes").innerHTML = barcodes.map(barcode => barcode.rawValue).join(', ');
          step(capturer);
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.error(e);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Did not work for me. Gave Promise rejected error

Answer (score 0):

Reviving an old thread here.
It is not supported in desktop browsers, only mobile browsers.

Here's my working code:

```
getImage(event) {

   let file: File = event.target.files[0];
   let myReader: FileReader = new FileReader();

   let barcode = window['BarcodeDetector'];
   let pdf = new barcode(["pdf417"]);

   createImageBitmap(file)
     .then(img => pdf.detect(img))
     .then(resp => {
       alert(resp[0].rawValue);
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It took some back and forth, but we finally have reliable feature detection for this API, see the [article](https://web.dev/shape-detection/#featuredetection) for full details. This is the relevant code snippet:

```js
await BarcodeDetector.getSupportedFormats();
/* On a macOS computer logs
  [
    "aztec",
    "code_128",
    "code_39",
    "code_93",
    "data_matrix",
    "ean_13",
    "ean_8",
    "itf",
    "pdf417",
    "qr_code",
    "upc_e"
  ]
*/
```

This allows you to detect the specific feature you need, for example, QR code scanning:

```js
if (('BarcodeDetector' in window) &&
    ((await BarcodeDetector.getSupportedFormats()).includes('qr_code'))) {
  console.log('QR code scanning is supported.');
}
```